# How to have a centralized MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to setup a MySQL database that takes data from 3 other MySQL databases. The data that would be copied would be a query that standardizes the data format. The method would need to either be run daily as a script or synced in real time, either method would be fine for this project.

For example:
The query from source DB: 
SELECT order_id, rate, quantity
WHERE date_order_placed = CUR_DATE()
FROM orders

Then I want to take the results of that query to be inserted into a destination DB.

The databases are on separate hosts.

I have tried creating scripts that run CSV and SQL exports/imports without success. I have also tried using Python pymysql library but seemed overkill. I'm pretty lost haha.

Thanks :)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: What you are referring to is called an ETL (extract, transform, load). There are many tools to do this, both paid and free. Your job is simple, so you could get away with scripting if you wanted. Take a look at bulk loading so you can grab a chunk from source, do whatever, and insert the chunk to the destination.

Comment: @Brian just what I was looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: Consider multi-source replication for continuous updating.

Comment: @RickJames would that be done on the centralized database as a MySQL task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A:

Connect to source.  SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE.
Connect to destination.  LOAD DATA INFILE from the output above.

Plan B (both MySQL):

Set up Replication from the source (as a Master) and the destination (as a Slave)

Plan C (3 MySQL servers):

Multi-source replication to allow gathering data from two sources into a single, combined, destination.

I think MariaDB 10.0 is when they introduced multi-source repl.  Caution: MariaDB's GTIDs are different than MySQL's.  But I think there is a way to make the replication you seek to work.  (It may be as simple as turning off GTIDs??)

Plan D (as mentioned):

Some ETL software.

Please ponder which Plan you would like to pursue, then ask for help in focusing on one.  Meanwhile, your question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for making my options clear. Plan C, Multi-source replication, seems like the best option but is only available on the newest version of MySQL (5.7). My versions are at 5.5 and 5.6. So I'm stumped on that option.

Comment: Alas.  MariaDB and Galera (on top of MySQL or MariaDB) had multi-source replication before Oracle's MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks will try using MariaDB as the multi-source slave to the 5.5 and 5.6 versions of MySQL.

Comment: @AnthonyAttard - I augmented Plan C with a reply.

Comment: Good point may be best to avoid using both MariaDB and MySQL together. Galera Cluster for MySQL seems like the best solution to keep things only in MySQL while allowing for multi-source replication.